# What does the first number represent in the damage section of some monster/NPC attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, damage

I understand most of what each number represents, but monster/NPC statblocks often have a number in the damage section before the damage roll in parentheses. For example, for a [Sahuagin Priestess](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/sahuagin-priestess) (MM, p. 264), one of her attacks looks like this:

> ***Bite.*** *Melee Weapon Attack:* +3 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. *Hit:* 3 (1d4 + 1) piercing damage.

What does the 3 in "3 (1d4 + 1)" mean?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour] for an easy badge. Great first question. I edited it a tiny bit to fit in with the site (for example, you don't need to put the game system in the title). Look forward to seeing you around!

Answer (score 28):

### It represents average damage

The Introduction to the *Monster Manual* discusses how to read the damage of attacks in the stat block:

> **Hit.** Any damage dealt or other effects that occur as a result of an attack hitting a target are described after the “Hit” notation. You have the option of taking average damage or rolling the damage; for this reason, both the average damage and the die expression are presented.

The average result of 1d4 + 1 is 3.5, which rounds down to 3.

Comment: So as the person being hit, always take the average? (since it's rounded down)

Comment: @Hobbamok no, only if the DM does not want to roll

Comment: I feel it is to help speed things up, it saves the DM having to roll dmg every time for every mob.

Answer (score 10):

## The 3 is the average damage.

Some DMs prefer to save time by using average damage instead of rolling every time.  The average is calculated as you'd expect: ([min damage] + [max damage]) / 2, and then rounded down.  In the case of your example, this results in (2 + 5) / 2 = 3.5.  The 3.5 is then rounded down to 3 to get the average damage.

Answer (score 6):

That 3 represents the average value of the damage roll; i.e. on average if you roll 1d4+1 you'll get 3. It's for simplicity's sake and you can use it if you want less randomness as a DM.

Answer (score 4):

The 3 is the average damage done by her bite (rounded down). Inside the parentheses is the formula for rolling damage.

1d4 (one four sided die) + 1: For possible values of 2-5. (2+5)/2 = 3.5.

Depending on the size of the encounter, you may choose to use average damage instead of rolling damage for every instance.